# Separable DE: Solve $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 2x + y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve:

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 2x + y$$

I know how to solve separable equations, but I got stuck on this inseparable one. How should I approach this equation?

Comment: What other types of ODEs have you learned about? Linear first-order, perhaps?

Comment: You could substitute $u=2x+y$ so that $u'=2+y'=2+u$ which is again separable.

Comment: @Lundmark yeah, only linear first-order.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac d {dx} (e^{-x}y)=e^{-x} (2x+y-y)=e^{-x}(2x)$. Integrate this equation.

Comment: Could you explain what you did exactly to get there?

Comment: @MihaiBurța: The method is called "integrating factor".

Answer (score 0):

$y'=2x+y\iff y'-y=2x\;$ is a non-homogeneous linear differential equation. The general metod here consists  in

- solving the associated homogeneous equation 
  $\;y'-y=0$,
- finding a particular solution $y_0$  of the non-homogeneous equation. As the r.h.s.  is a polynomial function, you can find as a particular solution a polynomial of the same degree, i.e. $y_0=ax+b$,
- adding  this particular solution to the general solution of the homogeneous equation to obtain the general solution of the non-homogeneous equation.